# Pandas pivot table to excel seperated sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, publish, save-as

I have pandas pivot table looks like below;

```
Region     Dist     A     B      C
X          T        1     2     0,5
X          V        2     2,5   3
Z          T        3     5     8,6
Y          P        8,6   7,2   3
Y          V        4,5   6,5   5
Z          V        7     3,3   4,8
Y          T        2     1,6   2,2
X          P        3     3,3   2,5
Z          P        5,5   6     8
```

so I made all the calculations and now I want to write to excel for publishing but I couldn't find how to write it seperately by 'Region'. In this case it'll be 3 worksheets as X,Y,Z but how can I code it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for looping by groups with [`ExcelWriter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-disk):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx') as writer:
    df.groupby('Region').apply(lambda x: x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=x.name, index=False))
```

Alternative:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, x in df.groupby('Region'):
        x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, index=False)
```

If need remove `Region` column in output:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, x in df.groupby('Region'):
        x.drop('Region', axis=1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, index=False)
```

Comment: really thanks for detailed answer, unfortunately I get "object of type "int" has no len()" error. Why do you think it happens?

Comment: @Tyr  How working `sheet_name=str(x.name)` or `sheet_name=str(i)` ? If not, what is your pandas version? If not last pandas 0.23.0 is possible upgrade?